# O endereço IP pode ser forjado?

Tags: segurança, ip, aplicação-web

Quando um cliente se conecta ao meu servidor, posso confiar que o endereço IP a que tenho acesso (toda linguagem/framework/etc usada em aplicações web expõe o IP do cliente de alguma forma) é realmente desse cliente? Ou ele pode ser forjado?

Sei que de um modo geral não devo confiar em nada que venha do lado cliente. Entretanto, também sei que, pelo modo como as redes funcionam, se um atacante de alguma forma me mandar uma mensagem com um IP falso a resposta não vai para ele - vai para o dono verdadeiro do IP informado. Me parece então que não é possível roubar informações de um usuário copiando o IP dele, ou estou enganado?

Em que medida eu posso confiar nessa informação ao validar uma requisição vinda do lado cliente?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Infelizmente existem técnicas de `spoof` uma delas chamada de [IPSpoofing](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_spoofing) que são utilizadas para falsificar endereços IPs,  é possível literalmente entrar no meio da comunicação entre  cliente e servidor e tomar a conexão da vítima, todas as seções abertas no monento entre o cliente e servidor são entregues ao forjador, isso só é possível porque outra técnica é utilizada em conjunto com IPSpoofing a chamada `session hijack` isso sim é realmente perigoso, a combinação das duas técnicas é alarmante pois permite a interceptação(roubo) do trafego de qualquer protocolo para o endereço forjado, quando eu digo "tomar conexão" é no sentido literal da palavra, imagine você na sua casa fazendo uma conexão ssh ou telnet para algum servidor, se um ataque deste tipo acontecer no instante que sua seção estiver aberta o atacante assume seu lugar, ele literalmente se conectou sem ter senha ssh/telnet. Na década de 90 isso era realmente muito perigo, até existe uma história lendária do hacker Kevin Mitnick utilizando ambas as técnica para interceptar conexões!

Hoje em dia a maioria dos roteadores descentes possuem nativamente opções de proteção contra spoof na tentativa de filtrar e detectar pacotes forjados!

Infelizmente nem todos conhecem e entendem a gravidade do assunto e não habilitam em suas redes este tipo de proteção, isso permite ataques de técnicas derivadas tão graves quanto, como por exemplo o [ARP Spoof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing), atualmente é muito utilizado em redes publicas como por exemplo em redes wireless, isso permite forjar requisições ARP e redirecionar todo o tráfego da rede para o atacante que utiliza de sniffers para capturar informações que estão trafegando, se isso for utilizado com outra técnica que consiga forjar conexões de criptografia como SSL a coisa fica extremamente perigosa e é possível capturar senhas, conversas, etc, etc...

**EDIT**

Bom vamos lá o Wikipedia neste caso te dá apenas uma abordagem superficial, tentando responder sua dúvida do comentário podemos ir um pouco além, eu não quero abrir aqui um tópico que sirva como ponte para má intencionados, mas este tipo de ataque quando feito fora de sua rede é realmente considerado um ataque cego, quando uma comunicação TCP é estabelecida com sucesso (Você pode estudar a fundo a arquitetura TCP-IP, para entender melhor o processo) fica bem definido entre as partes que se comunicam o número inicial de sequencia que é enviado juntamente com o pacote SYN+ACK, o ataque é cego pois o forjador não faz a mínima ideia de qual número inicial foi estabelecido para poder predizer qual será a próxima sequencia e sem isso não existe comunicação e sem comunicação não existe resposta, "mas", sempre tem um "mas", existem maneiras de tentar descobrir esse número e gerar a próxima sequencia esperada, com essa informação existe conversa, olha só isso é extremamente complexo, é complicado mas não impossível.

Se o Spoof vier de dentro de sua rede as coisas ficam mais fáceis pois o ataque não é considerado cego, com um sniffer é possível capturar e analisar os pacotes entre dois hosts e conhecer quais são as sequencias...

Você falou de MitM de fato o IPSpoof é classificado como parte integrante para a execução de um MitM. O MitM além de interceptar os dados pode retransmitir de forma original ou alterada (arp spoof está bem próximo de ser um MitM de fato ele é usado como ponte para o próximo passo que seria não apenas capturar dados, mas sim retransmitir alterados ou não), o cenário descrito foi um exemplo de IpSpoof utilizando técnicas de hijack session, todas elas usam IPSpoof como ponte de exploração.

O cenário tanto importa tudo está acontecendo antes da camada de aplicação, eu me lembro que fiquei encafifado com esse tipo de falha na arquitetura tcp/ip no ano 2000, eu montei um ambiente para testar estas situações, fiz testes com telnet na época e foi alarmante :-(

**EDIT 2**

Se você está preocupado com o endereço público do cliente se ele foi forjado ou não, "olhar" o IP público não garante a segurança para a sua aplicação Web e se o IP fosse realmente falso (spoofado) você nem teria artifícios para identificar e tomar alguma ação, clientes mal intencionados vão se preocupar em dificultar o máximo possível que o IP real esteja em seus logs (da sua aplicação Web), nestes casos se o cliente se conectar atrás de um proxy qualquer aberto pelo mundo você só vai ter o endereço IP público feito através do Proxy e o endereço verdadeiro do cliente somente o dono do Proxy vai poder te falar, conseguir esta informação vai depender talvez de exigências judiciais requisitando que o proxy repasse para você essa informação, estes proxys abertos já são usados como ponte de ataque por estes motivos, de modo geral não possuem gerencia muito menos logs com as informações de quem se conectou na data X e na hora Y o que deixa o atacante impune, Uma maneira de tentar checar o endereço público que se conecta em sua aplicação é submeter o endereço do IP público para alguma lista RBL como por exemplo essa http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx, nela um IP é submetido a várias RBLs que classificam se um IP está "limpo" mas isso mais uma vez não garante muita coisa, estes checks apenas olham se determinado IP tem registro de envio de vírus, trojans, botnets, spam, etc, etc, problemas neste sentido, mais uma vez se o cliente estiver atras de algum proxy é o IP público do Proxy que você vai estar submetendo.

Então Verificar o IP de quem se conecta não faz muito sentido a não ser que você esteja fechando conexão para um determinado grupo de clientes com IP's estáticos. Só com a informação do IP que se conecta em sua aplicação não te traz garantias de segurança em absolutamente nada.

Comment: Estou um pouco confuso: esse cenário que você descreveu é diferente de um MitM entre o cliente e o servidor, certo? Pois o artigo da Wikipedia linkado diz "Além disso as características do protocolo IP permitem falsificar um remetente, porém não permitem receber as respostas — essas irão para o endereço falsificado. Assim, o ataque pode ser considerado *cego*". Como um atacante poderia capturar sua conexão ssh através dessa técnica? (veja bem que não estou duvidando, longe disso, é que eu fiz a pergunta pra entender melhor como o processo funciona, mas sua resposta me confundiu ainda mais)

Comment: Veja se o EDIT ajuda a elucidar...

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigado! Quando fiz a pergunta, estava pensando do ponto de vista de uma aplicação web que usa o IP do cliente como parte do processo de autenticação/validação. Por isso meu foco era no IP público. Pelo que eu entendi do ARP Spoof, ele ocorre dentro da rede do usuário, atuando sobre o IP privado, certo? Nesse cenário, um observador externo não detectaria nada de "suspeito" acontecendo (pois o IP público seria o mesmo), ainda que um ataque desses - incluindo MitM - fosse bem sucedido. De todo modo, muito boa a resposta! +1

Comment: Eu gostei muito desta discussão. Pode ser meio off-topic, mas você tem ideia se o uso do [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) pode evitar este ataque?

Comment: De maneira alguma, o Tor nestes casos funcionaria como uma pitada a mais no tempero, dificultando a rastreabilidade da origem do ataque. A rede Tor Utiliza protocolo TCP IP para comunicação então está suscetível a ataques spoof da mesma maneira ...